# Аналог MBProgressHUD на Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

В Objective-C проектах, при запросах к серверу, пользовался MBProgressHUD для блокирования интерфейса и показа спиннера.

https://cocoapods.org/pods/MBProgressHUD

Очень нравился. Но в чисто свифтовый проект не хочется тащить зависимости на obj-c

Посоветуйте аналогичный pod на Swift. Кастомизируемый, лаконичный, продуманный, надежный.

Comment: В чем проблема в подами на ObjC в Swift-проекте? Это наоборот не стоит. А ObjC вам ничего не испортит.

Comment: все. нет уже obj-c ) он умер )) во всяком случае, для некоторых

Comment: Пусть умер, но что мешает использовать его наследие? :)

Comment: в вопросе это есть: "Но в чисто свифтовый проект не хочется тащить зависимости на obj-c". Если нет аналога на swift, то может, но если есть, то я бы хотел pod на swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Интересный подход, какая разница на чем написана библиотека, если она отлично выполняет то что от нее требуется и уже имеется положительный опыт при работе с ней?

В конце-концов все эти `Swift`, `Objective-C` и другие - всего-лишь синтаксический сахар над `0` и `1`.

Ну и по вопросу, посмотрите на

[NVActivityIndicatorView](https://github.com/ninjaprox/NVActivityIndicatorView)

Использовал в одном из последних проектов - проста и есть интересные анимациии.

Answer (score 1):

Полностью кастомизируемый [Indicator](https://github.com/epodkorytov/Indicator)

Comment: 0 звездочек и релиз 3 месяца назад - а хочется чего-нибудь проверенного, надежного и не страдающего детскими болезнями)

Comment: А! ну звёздочки это конечно решают.

Comment: под условие не подходит: нужен "надежный", а с вашим непонятно пока какой он, никто его еще успел проверить. но +1 за ответ от меня вы получили )

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю еще несколько библиотек на swift

[AMProgressHUD](https://github.com/Abedalkareem/AMProgressHUD)

[VKProgressHud](https://github.com/VamshiIITBHU14/VKProgressHud)

[LottieHUD](https://github.com/ahmedraad/LottieHUD)

[SwiftLoader](https://github.com/leoru/SwiftLoader)

[ARSLineProgress](https://github.com/soberman/ARSLineProgress)

[ZVProgressHUD](https://github.com/zevwings/ZVProgressHUD)

Answer (score 0):

Вот этот парень переписал MBProgressHUD на Swift – можно воспользоваться этим портом.
[HKProgressHUD](https://github.com/huaweikang/HKProgressHUD)